# Error deploying the apache:superset image on Kubernetes

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, apache-superset

I am trying to deploy the latest docker image `apache:superset` on Kubernetes. When I deploy the YAML I get below error:

```
[2021-04-29 01:34:10 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-04-29 01:34:10 +0000] [8] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8088 (8)
[2021-04-29 01:34:10 +0000] [8] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2021-04-29 01:34:10 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
logging was configured successfully
2021-04-29 01:34:12,332:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
2021-04-29 01:34:12,340:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
100.106.25.194 - - [29/Apr/2021:01:34:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 243 "-" "kube-probe/1.18"
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py:192: UserWarning: Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
  "Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, "
2021-04-29 01:34:20,145:WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped
2021-04-29 01:34:20,147:ERROR:root:DBEventLogger failed to log event(s)
2021-04-29 01:34:20,147:ERROR:root:(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: logs
[SQL: INSERT INTO logs (action, slice_id, json, dttm, duration_ms, referrer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('welcome', 0, '{"path": "/superset/welcome/", "object_ref": "Superset.welcome"}', '2021-04-29 01:34:20.147331', 0, 'http://100.106.25.213:8088/')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: logs
```

It seems it is trying to connect to default SQLLite. I am trying to give postgres credentials in config.py but not able to modify the file in the image. I have below command in my Docker file:

```
USER root
COPY updated_config.py /app/superset/config.py
USER superset
```

the command runs fine but not updating the file.How can I update the config.py. I also tried using Config Map in YAML but that also gave error:

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'superset.app'"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The error which you shared should happen only when we didn't run `superset db upgrade`.
2. You should not replace complete default config file. Instead create new file and added necessary variables with export *SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH*.

Here Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/superset
USER root

USER superset
EXPOSE 8088

RUN superset fab create-admin \
               --username admin \
               --firstname Superset \
               --lastname Admin \
               --email admin@superset.com \
               --password admin

COPY updated_config.py /app/config.py
RUN export SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/app/config.py
RUN superset db upgrade

RUN superset init
```

I'll better suggest install superset through helm chart as you already using kubernetes.